# Got syntax error can't understand what is wrong

Tags: postgresql

Need you help please tell me what i am doing wrong in that function ? 
According to docs examples all should work .. [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS)

```
create or replace function loginValidator(nickname varchar, email varchar, u_password varchar) returns boolean as $$
DECLARE
    checked boolean := false; n_regex varchar; e_regex varchar; p_regex varchar;
BEGIN 

 BEGIN;

  select nickname_r into n_regex from regex;
  select email_r into e_regex from regex;
  select password_r into p_regex from regex;

  IF n_regex ~ nickname AND e_regex ~ email AND p_regex ~ u_password THEN checked := true;

 COMMIT;

 return checked;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
>   LINE 6:   BEGIN;
>                  ^
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `END IF`. I would rewrite it as:

```
create or replace function loginValidator(nickname varchar,
                                          email varchar,
                                          u_password varchar)
returns boolean 
as
$$
DECLARE
    checked boolean := false; n_regex varchar; e_regex varchar; p_regex varchar;
BEGIN 
  -- removed BEGIN
  select nickname_r, email_r, password_r into n_regex, e_regex, p_regex from regex;

  IF n_regex ~ nickname AND e_regex ~ email AND p_regex ~ u_password 
  THEN checked := true;
  END IF;    -- added END IF;
  -- removed COMMIT;

  RETURN checked;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

or even simpler:

```
create or replace function loginValidator(nickname varchar,
                                          email varchar,
                                          u_password varchar)
returns boolean 
as
$$
BEGIN 

  RETURN  (select COUNT(*) 
          from regex
          WHERE nickname_r ~ nickname
            AND  email_r ~ email
            AND password_r ~ u_password)::boolean;

END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I hope that you are not stroring passwords as clear text.